# Logstash RabbitMQ output plugin

Tags: logstash, rabbitmq

I am a new to Logstash and
I want to store nginx messages in RabbitMQ queue like this:

Nginx logs -(input)-> Logstash -(output)-> RabbitMQ

logstash config:

```
filter {
   grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:remote_ip} - %{DATA:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:access_time}\] \"%{WORD:http_method} %{DATA:url} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}\" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:body_sent_bytes} \"%{DATA:referrer}\" \"%{DATA:agent}\"" }
   }
}
output {
  rabbitmq {
    exchange => "nginx_app"
    host => "localhost"
    exchange_type => "topic"
    persistent => true
    passive => true
    heartbeat => 10
    arguments => {"x-ha-policy" => "all" }
    codec => "plain"
    port => 5672
  }
}
```

During debugging in RabbitMQ web console I see the following: message are visible to RabbitMQ but it doesn't save them in the queue in the same time when I use simple python script to add message to the queue everthing is saved),
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5xk8.png)

what's wrong with my config?
Why RabbitMQ doesn't save messages?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of my issue, I needed to add a binding to my queue, after adding the binding, every message logged correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9t5p.png)